# StringTemplate rendering map as literal value

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Using `org.stringtemplate.v4.ST` I am trying to render this template:

```
$if(foo.map)$Foo Map: <foo.map.keys:{k | <k>: <foo.map.(k)>}; separator="\n"><br/>$endif$
```

When the `st.render()` method is invoked, this is printed out:

```
Foo Map: <foo.map.keys:{k | <k>: <foo.map.(k)>}; separator="\n"><br/>
```

Even though I have set the values in `foo.map` they are not printed out. How do I print the values instead of the template literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tried it out. But on the first view. Your delimiter is '$' for start and end. And not '<', '>'. So this should do the trick:

```
$if(foo.map)$Foo Map: $foo.map.keys:{k | $k$: $foo.map.(k)$}; separator="\n"$<br/>$endif$
```